# Sqrt of constant representation in Julia Symbolics

Tags: julia, symbolic-math

I am looking for a way to represent a symbolic expression such as `sqrt(3)*x` so as to avoid `sqrt(3)` being calculated upfront.

Sample code:

```
using Symbolics
@variables x
y = sqrt(3)*x
```

Showing y, we can see that sqrt(3) has become a floating point.

Is there a mechanism to keep the sqrt in symbolic form?

Comment: Are you speaking of `(1/3)x` or `(1//3)x` ? Because `(1//3)x` works as expected...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a mechanism to keep the sqrt in symbolic form?

```
julia> using Symbolics
julia> @variables x
(x,)
julia> y = Symbolics.Term(sqrt,[3])*x

x*sqrt(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I have been looking for Symbolics thorough documentation but only found something basic. Could you provide a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce:

```
julia> using Symbolics

julia> @variables x
(x,)

julia> y = 1//3*x
(1//3)*x

julia> y
(1//3)*x
```

My config:

```
[0c5d862f] Symbolics v0.1.21
```

and

```
julia> versioninfo()

Julia Version 1.6.0
Commit f9720dc2eb (2021-03-24 12:55 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-11.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
```

Comment: Sorry, I remember the problem. It was sqrt(3). Thanks for your follow up though. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, y = 1//3 * x works, but not y = sqrt(3) * x as according to the orignal question. So, the answer from user Nasser is really helpful thanks.

Comment: Thinking about it, when calling sqrt with am integer of float, multiple dispatch will call sqrt(::Int64) or sqrt(::Float64). However, when using the `//` operator between an Int64 and a Symbolics Num, multiple dispatch will select the corresponding function with a signature `operator // (Int64, Symbolics.Num)`